# Is there a way to turn these multiple SQL queries into one?

Tags: sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   table
WHERE  date_field >= '2018-04-08'
AND    date_field <= '2018-04-14'
```

I need to do this 26 times, for the current week and for 25 previous weeks, with each result separated by a carriage return. Is this possible with a single SQL query or do I need to put it in a loop, as I'm now doing?

> Note that this is in FileMaker. I don't *think* that's relevant, but now you know, just in case.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? what should the final outcome look like?

Comment: This is in FileMaker. The final outcome is a list of counts sorted by the week they occur within separated by carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using "group by". Assuming that you are looking at calendar weeks, grouping by the week of the date will give you the counts per week and an extra condition can limit the overall range.

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker has a WeekOfYearFiscal() function.  2nd parameter is the day of week start date.

```
SELECT WeekOfYearFiscal(dateField;2), COUNT(*)
FROM   table
WHERE  date_field >= '2018-01-01'
AND    date_field <= '2018-04-14'
group by WeekOfYearFiscal(dateField;2)
```

See this documentation - http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.28.html

Give this a go.  If the GROUP BY doesn't work on the function, you can nest the inner part and give an alias.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but `WeekOfYearFiscal` is a *FileMaker* function, not a FileMaker SQL function. I looked through the SQL functions supported by FileMaker, and nothing like `WeekOfYearFiscal` is included. The closest I see is `DAYOFWEEK`.